# Where could I sell micro BTC and is it possible?

Tags: transactions

I would like to know if is it ok to sell micro BTC? Like a few decimal places like 0.01 BTC? And where would I sell it to exchange for other currencies? And how do I get the exchange safely?

Answer (score 2):

The smallest part of a bitcoin is (currently) called 1 satoshi, and it is equal to 0.00000001 BTC. So selling 0.01 BTC is no problem on any exchange, you only have to take into account the fees which are asked by the exchange. If it's a percentage (as it usually is) you're fine.

If you want to sell you can use big sites like bitstamp, coinbase etc.
To trade for other cryptocurrencies you can use btc-e, kraken, cryptsy, ...

Comment: OK, so my 0.01 is actually equal to 1 million satoshis?
Percentage fees? is it a lot?
And I'd like to sell them for USD for example, and not other cryptocurrencies.

Comment: Indeed, 1 million satoshis. Bitstamp.net charges 0.5%, other exchanges do something similar. If you are US-based you'd be better of with a US site, such as coinbase.

Answer (score -2):

If all you want to do is trade for altcoins, I've found that Crypsy is pretty good.